# How to disable "Slow" tagged Scalatests by default, allow execution with option?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, scalatest

I want to disable certain automated tests tagged as "Slow" by default but allow the user to enable their execution with a simple command line. I imagine this is a very common use case.

Given this test suite:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.tagobjects.Slow

class DemoTestSuite extends FunSuite {
  test("demo test tagged as slow", Slow) {
    assert(1 + 1 === 2)
  }

  test("demo untagged test") {
    assert(1 + 1 === 2)
  }
}
```

By default, `sbt test` will run both tagged and untagged tests.

If I add the following to my build.sbt:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-l", "org.scalatest.tags.Slow")
```

Then I get my desired default behavior where untagged tests run and the Slow tagged test will not run.

However, I can't figure out a command line option that will run the slow tests when I want to run them. I've done several searches and tried several examples. I'm somewhat surprised as this seems like a very common scenario.

Comment: Have you checked [this article](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scalatest-mark-tests-tags-to-include-exclude-sbt) out?

Comment: @evan058, yes, and that works, but it leaves the default behavior to run everything. I'd like the default to exclude slow tests.

Comment: Have you tried `testOnly org.myorg.* -- -n org.scalatest.tags.Slow`? From [this page](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt), section "Include and Exclude Tests with Tags".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue: I wanted to have tests that are *disabled by default*, but run in the *release process*. I solved it by creating a [custom test configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Custom+test+configuration) and setting `testOptions` in different scopes. So adapting this solution to your case, it should be something along these lines (in your `build.sbt`):

```
lazy val Slow = config("slow").extend(Test)
configs(Slow)
inConfig(Slow)(Defaults.testTasks)
```

Now by default exclude slow tests:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-l", "org.scalatest.tags.Slow")
```

But in the `Slow` scope don't exclude them and run only them:

```
testOptions in Slow -= Tests.Argument("-l", "org.scalatest.tags.Slow")
testOptions in Slow += Tests.Argument("-n", "org.scalatest.tags.Slow")
```

Now when you run `test` in sbt, it will run everything except slow test and when you run `slow:test` it will run *only* slow tests.

Comment: Note: `lazy val Slow` goes into the top level, for multi-project builds, while `configs` and `inConfig` are per-project. See also https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Additional+test+configurations+with+shared+sources