# Override project's setting inside of SBT task

Tags: sbt

In my build.sbt a compilation phase depends on running scapegoat inspection

```
(compile in Compile) := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(scapegoat).value
```

I'm trying to introduce a new task for running tests (for development purposes to speed things up) that does not depend on scapegoat like this:

```
lazy val fastTests = taskKey[Unit]("")

fastTests := {
  scapegoat in Compile := {}
  (test in Test).value
}
```

but gets ignored

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with a task because tasks cannot change settings. You can solve it either with different configurations or with a command (which can change settings). See for example:

- [How to disable “Slow” tagged Scalatests by default, allow execution with option?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269896/736957)
   (for the configurations approach)
- [How to change setting inside SBT command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262798/736957)